# How to find all directories within a directory beginning with a particular prefix?

Tags: bash, shell

Using a shell script, I'd like to find all directories within a directory (not recursively) that begin with a particular prefix, then loop through them. Pseudocode example:

```
array directories = find('/etc/build', 'project-build-*');
foreach (string directory in directories)
{
    // directory == 'project-build-example-x64'
    do_something_with('/etc/build/' + directory + '/Makefile');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for dir in "/etc/build/project-build-"*/
do
  do_something_with "$dir"Makefile
done
```

Comment: Wow, that's really intuitive! Thanks.

Comment: As a followup, this still executes once with the pattern itself if there are no matches... how would I fix that?

Comment: Set the `nullglob` option. `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: Which will cause the loop not to execute at all if there are no matches, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative with `find` and `xargs`

```
find /etc/build/project-build-*/ -maxdepth 1 -name Makefile | xargs do_something
```